# How to fix Debug Error from Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime library when dealing with threads?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm writing a program that will detect a key press and do something (in this case, show a message box).

It all works fine, except when I try to exit the program, it shows a popup like this error window:

[image]

Now, this window doesn't mess up anything in my program, so I could leave it there, but it is annoying.

Here's a Minimal Reproducible Sample, I'm just beginning to code in Win32 so please don't criticize my inefficent code.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#define HFFFA               1001
#define MAINWINDOWSTYLE         WS_OVERLAPPED| WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX
std::chrono::milliseconds THREAD_WAIT(50);

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
    {

        switch (wp)
        {
        case HFFFA:
        {

            MessageBox(hwnd, L"Sucess", L"Success", MB_OK);
            break;
        }
        break;
        }

        break;

    }
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW));
        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        break;
    }
    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }
     break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wp, lp);
}


void GetKeyPress(HWND hwnd)
{
    int keypressed = -1;
    while (TRUE)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F6))
        {
            SendMessage(hwnd, WM_COMMAND, (WPARAM)HFFFA, TRUE);
        }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(THREAD_WAIT);
    }
}


int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hinst, HINSTANCE hiprevinst, PWSTR nCmdLine, int ncmdshow)
{
    const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[] = L"Axom";
    WNDCLASS wc = { };
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.hInstance = hinst;
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    RegisterClass(&wc);
    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, CLASS_NAME, L"Axom", MAINWINDOWSTYLE, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 592, 600, NULL, NULL, hinst, NULL);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, ncmdshow);
    std::thread td(GetKeyPress, hwnd);
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are looking for [`RegisterHotKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerhotkey).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the events loop ends, all of `wWinMain`'s local variables are destroyed. One of them is `td` as your thread. When `std::thread` is destroyed while it is in joinable state, `std::terminate()` is called:

> [std::terminate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate)
> is called by the C++ runtime when the program cannot continue for any of the following reasons:
>
> 10. a joinable std::thread is destroyed or assigned to

The default `std::terminate()` behaviour is to invoke the `std::abort()` function.

> The default std::terminate_handler calls std::abort.

You have to call `detach()` or `join()` on the `td` thread before it is destroyed. If you join the thread, you have to add some mechanism (for example, via a global flag variable) to inform the `GetKeyPress` thread function when to leave.

```
std::atomic_bool stopFlag; // global variable

void GetKeyPress(HWND hwnd) {
    int keypressed = -1;
    while (!stopFlag) {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F6))
           SendMessage(hwnd, WM_COMMAND, (WPARAM)HFFFA, TRUE);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(THREAD_WAIT);
    }
}

std::thread td(GetKeyPress, hwnd);
MSG msg;
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
stopFlag = true;
td.join();
```

Comment: Re: "You have to detach or join `td`" -- yes, either of those will treat the symptom, but `detach` is almost always the wrong answer. +1.